# Topological weakly mixing implies totally transitive

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

I'm currently reading the first chapter of Grosse-Erdmann & Peris Manguillot's book *Linear Chaos*, which chapter is about topological dynamical systems and I got stuck in an exercise which says that if $T$ is a dynamical system which is weakly mixing then $T$ is totally transitive:

[image]

Could someone give me a hint or a solution? Thanks in advance. I forgot to mention that a topological dynamical system is just a metric space $X$ with a continuous map $T : X \to X$ defined on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The main tool to use is the Furstenberg Theorem (Thm.1.51 on p.20 of the text you are citing); that says that if a system is topologically weak mixing (TWM), then any Cartesian power of it is also TWM.

---

Let us fix some notations. Let $X$ be a topological space, $T:X\to X$ be a continuous self-map of $X$. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$: denote by

$$T^n=\underbrace{T\circ T\circ\cdots \circ T}_{n\text{ times}}:X\to X$$

the $n$-fold composition of $T$ with itself. For $q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ denote by

$$T^{(q)}=\underbrace{T\times T\times\cdots \times T}_{p\text{ times}}:X^q\to X^q$$

the $p$-fold Cartesian product of $T$ with itself, where $X^q=\underbrace{X\times X\times\cdots \times X}_{p\text{ times}}$.

Denote by $\mathcal{T}(X)^\ast$ the collection of all nonempty open subsets of $X$.

**Definition:** $T:X\to X$ is called:

- **topologically transitive (TT)** if $\forall U,V\in \mathcal{T}(X)^\ast,\exists n=n(T;U\to V)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}: T^n(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset$.
- **totally topologically transitive (TTT)** if $\forall p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}: T^p:X\to X$ is TT.
- **topologically weak mixing (TWM)** if $T^{(2)}:X^2\to X^2$ is TT.
- **totally topologically weak mixing (TTWM)** if $\forall p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}: T^p:X\to X$ is TWM.
- **topologically strong mixing (TSM)** if $\forall U,V\in \mathcal{T}(X)^\ast,\exists N=N(T;U\to V)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1},\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq N}: T^n(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset$.
- **totally topologically strong mixing (TTSM)** if $\forall p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}: T^p:X\to X$ is TSM.

Putting together the fact that any factor of a TWM system is TWM (Prop.1.48 on p.19) and the Furstenberg Theorem mentioned above we have:

**Theorem:** The following are equivalent:

- $T:X\to X$ is TWM,
- $\exists q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}:T^{(q)}:X^q\to X^q$ is TWM,
- $\forall q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}:T^{(q)}:X^q\to X^q$ is TWM.

---

**Claim:** If $T:X\to X$ is TWM, then  it is also TTWM, hence consequently TTT.

**Proof of Claim:** Say $T$ is TWM. Fix a number $p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ and open subsets $U,V,W,Z\in\mathcal{T}(X)^\ast$. We need to show that there is a number $Q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ such that

$$T^{Qp}(U)\cap W\neq\emptyset\text{ and }T^{Qp}(V)\cap Z\neq\emptyset.$$

By the Furstenberg Theorem above, since $T$ is TWM we have that $T^{(p)}$ is TWM, i.e. by definition $T^{(2p)}=(T^{(p)})^{(2)}:X^{2p}\to X^{2p}$ is TT. Define two open sets in $X^{2p}$ as follows:

$$A=U\times T^{-1}(U)\times \cdots \times T^{-p+1}(U)\times V \times T^{-1}(V)\times \cdots \times T^{-p+1}(V),$$

$$B = \underbrace{W\times W\times \cdots\times W}_{p \text{ many}}\times \underbrace{Z\times Z\times \cdots \times Z}_{p\text{ many}}.$$

Since $T^{(2p)}$ is TT, there is a number $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ such that

$$\left(T^{(2p)}\right)^m(A)\cap B\neq \emptyset.$$

Note that we may assume that $m\geq p-1$ by applying the definition of TT to preimages of open sets ($\ast$). There are unique numbers $Q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ and $R\in\{0,1,...,p-1\}$ such that

$$m=Qp+R.$$

($Q$ and $R$ are uniquely determined by $m$ and $p$, but $m$ is not uniquely determined by the previous objects.)

Writing this out in terms of points, we have guaranteed that there exists $x_0,x_1,...,x_{p-1},y_0,y_1,...,y_{p-1}\in X $ such that

\begin{align*}
&u_0=x_0, u_1=T(x_1),..., u_{p-1}=T^{p-1}(x_{p-1})\in U\text{ and  }\\
&v_0=y_0, v_1=T(y_1),..., v_{p-1}=T^{p-1}(y_{p-1})\in V
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
&T^{m}(u_0)=T^{m}(x_0), T^{m-1}(u_1)=T^{m}(x_1),..., T^{m-p+1}(u_{p-1})=T^{m}(x_{p-1})\in W\text{ and  }\\
&T^{m}(v_0)=T^{m}(y_0), T^{m-1}(v_1)=T^{m}(y_1),..., T^{m-p+1}(v_{p-1})=T^{m}(y_{p-1})\in Z.
\end{align*}

Thus we have

$$T^{pQ}(u_R)=T^{m-R}(u_R)=T^m(x_R)\in W \text{ and } T^{pQ}(v_R)=T^{m-R}(v_R)=T^m(y_R)\in Z,$$

that is,

$$T^{pQ}(u_R)\in T^{pQ}(U)\cap W\text{ and } T^{pQ}(v_R)\in  T^{pQ}(V)\cap Z.$$

---

**Edit:** As per request here is an argument for ($\ast$): Let $T:X\to X$ be TT,  $U,V\subseteq X$ be nonempty open. Let $N\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$. $T^{-N}(V)$ is nonempty open, so for some $n=n(U\to T^{-N}(V))\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}:$ $T^n(U)\cap T^{-N}(V)\neq\emptyset$, whence $T^{N+n}(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset$.

A more detailed discussion about this matter can be found in my answer here: [Isolated Points and Topological Transitivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2805051/169085) . In particular, to be compatible with the conventions of the book in question, if $X$ is Hausdorff, topological transitivity with nonnegative return time is equivalent to topological transitivity with positive return time.

Comment: You say that  since T^{(2p)} is TT , then there exists  a number m \in  Z_{ >=1} such that T^{(2p)} (A) \cap B \neq \varnothing. The problem is that i don't see any m in the T^{(2p)} (A) \cap B \neq \varnothing. Could you please explain?

Comment: @JustTry Sorry, the $m$ was missing.

Comment: and everything else is right?

Comment: @JustTry I hope so.

Comment: i think that you have to write u_{0} = T^{m} (x_{0} ) etc. . Am I wrong?

Comment: There was indeed a mistake in the ordering; I've reordered the components of $A$ instead.

Comment: and one more question ,could you please explain how we can assume that m is greater than or equal to p-1? thanks in advance

Comment: @JustTry I've added some further details, let me know if it's not clear.