# How can I check that the following map is not topologically mixing?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, mixing

> Let me consider the matrix $$ M=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}  $$ We consider the associated markov shift $S:\Omega_M\rightarrow \Omega_M$ where $\Omega_M=\{\omega\in \{0,1,2,3\}^\Bbb{Z}: M(\omega_i,\omega_{i+1})=1~\forall i\in \Bbb{Z}\}$. I want to check if this markov shift is topologically mixing or not.

My claim is that it is not topologically mixing.

> We say that $T:X\rightarrow X$ is topologically mixing if for all $U,V\subset X$ open nonempty,  there exists $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $T^{-n}(U)\cap V\neq \emptyset$.

I wanted to take the following two sequences $u=...0100...$ where $u_1=0, u_2=1, u_3=0, u_4=0$ are fixed and similarly $v=...3233...$ where $v_1=3, v_2=2, v_3=3, v_4=3$ are fixed. Now define the set $$U:=\{\omega\in \Omega_M:\omega_1=0, \omega_2=1, \omega_3=0, \omega_4=0 \}$$ and $$V:=\{\omega\in \Omega_M:\omega_1=3, \omega_2=2, \omega_3=3, \omega_4=3 \}$$, then they are not empty and open. But now for every $N\in \Bbb{N}$ we can take $n=N$ and remark that $$S^{-n}(U)=\{\omega\in \Omega_M: \omega_{1-n}=0, \omega_{2-n}=1, \omega_{3-n}=0, \omega_{4-n}=0 \}$$ but then we see immediately that $S^{-n}(U)\cap V=\emptyset$ since there is no path $0$ or $1$ to $2$ or $3$ or vice versa using $M$. Therefore I would say $S$ not topologically mixing.

Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works. Your Markov shift is not topologically mixing. It is not even irreducible since there is no connection between the first two states and the other states.

Comment: perfect thanks a lot!